# How I select a specific <a> Element without an ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a specific `<a>` Element where the href is a JavaScript function. The call shall be from JavaScript code.

For example if we have a tag `<div id="ask-question">`. We will call that from javascript by `$("#ask-question").onClick()`. For now, my problem is `<a>` tag without id. How I can do it?

Full example of my `<a>` tag:

`<a class="update-receive" href="javascript:void(0)">Update & Reward</a>`

Comment: Select it by class name instead, or by something more specific that uniquely identifies it in the HTML. (while you *could* theoretically select it by the `javascript:void(0)` attribute, that's not good at all)

Comment: Call it by classname `$(".update-receive").onClick()`

Comment: You can call it by classname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```js
$("a.update-receive").click(function () {
  console.log("Update & Reward");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="update-receive" href="javascript:void(0)">Update & Reward</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:(Pure JavaScript)**

You can call function by `onclick` something like below:

Current:

```
<a class="update-receive" href="javascript:void(0)">Update & Reward</a>
```

Change to:

```
<a class="update-receive" href="#" onclick="myFunction();">Update & Reward</a>
```

Demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Update & Reward clicked");
}
```

```html
<a class="update-receive" href="#" onclick="myFunction();">Update & Reward</a>
```

**Option 2:(jQuery)**

Call function by class name using `jquery`

```js
$(".update-receive").click(function () {
  console.log("Update & Reward clicked");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="update-receive" href="#">Update & Reward</a>
```